# SQL Server 2016 Availability Group on DPM 2016

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2016, dpm

I'm trying to backup my availability group in SQL Server 2016 using DPM 2016, but after I add the cluster in DPM, availability group show nothing to back up. I've set every secondary node to be readable secondary and add sysadmin role to \SYSTEM user. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just should install update rollup 2 or above to detect SQL Server 2016 availability groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the cluster, as in the WSFC computer name, to DPM then this may not be correct according to the MS documentation and may explain why you have nothing to backup - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/dpm/back-up-sql-server?view=sc-dpm-1807

Try adding the Availability Group Replicas individually. DPM should detect the AG configuration automatically and, provided all replicas are readable, it should backup up according to the AG backup preferences.

Comment: Actually AG configuration has been detected in DPM, but when I expand it, there is nothing